# How do i process this ajax data?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How will i process this Ajax in php.
What i want to do is  send the data to process.php and if mode=loadlinks it will do a mysql query

```
function PresentLinks(div_id){

        $("#loading-status").fadeIn(900,0);
        $("#loading-status").html("<img src='img/bigLoader.gif' />");           

$.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: "mode=loadlinks",

            success: function(msg){

                $("#loading-status").fadeOut(900,0);
                $("#"+div_id).html(msg);


            }

        });}
```

What i want to process is

```
if($_POST['mode'] == loadlinks){  // this is what i want to ask
$query = "SELECT * FROM site ORDER BY link_id DESC";
$result = MYSQL_QUERY($query) or die (mysql_error());
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
echo ("$data[1]");
}}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote strings in PHP. Otherwise they will be assumed to be constants. You should also be using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo).

```
if($_POST['mode'] == 'loadlinks'){
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE'), 'username', 'password');
    $stmt = $pdo->execute('SELECT * FROM site ORDER BY link_id DESC');

    $sites = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach($sites as $site) {
        echo "<div>" . $site['name'] . "</div>"; // Or whatever info you want to output
    }
}
```

For performance you should be specifying table column names to retrieve instead of using `*`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to quote the string value

```
  if($_POST['mode'] == 'loadlinks'){.....
```

Comment: ...and don't quote variables: `echo ("$data[1]");` -> `echo $data[1];`  (or `echo "{$data[1]}";`, which would be pointless).